# how to get cutom module data from related list in vtiger

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I working on vtiger CRM, For this CRM i need to develop a plugin which after installation can be accessible through organization or leads details view.

I have successfully reached to this level of my plugin. for linking of my module i have used setRelatedList API and my code is

```
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php');
$moduleInstance = Vtiger_Module::getInstance('Payslip');
$accountsModule = Vtiger_Module::getInstance('Accounts');
$relationLabel  = 'Accounts';
$moduleInstance->setRelatedList(
      $accountsModule, $relationLabel, Array('ADD','SELECT')
);
```

My plugin's name is mailAddon, and it is showing on the side bar on builtin details module, not the task if when if click on my plugin, it should fetch data according to my requirements, from my defined table. I just want to know how to extend this behavior of vtiger.

Thanks

Comment: can i get any help for this ?

Answer (score 0):

It will be late but yes you can get your plugin data using default function as well as with custom function. To make this working just go to `vtiger_relatedlists` table and find your entry using your module tab id. Just update that row with function name as you missed in your code. You can set either function name to `get_dependents_list` or `get_related_list` as per your module structure. Here is the script as well where to and what to set. Hope this will help you.

http://prntscr.com/emny6v

Answer (score 0):

You need create one function in your module file (DIR = modules/YourModuleFolder/YourModuleName.php).
Here

```
function vtlib_handler($modulename, $event_type) {
   if ($event_type == 'module.postinstall') {
      $this->setModuleRelatedDependencies();
   } else if ($event_type == 'module.disabled') {
      $this->unsetModuleRelatedDependencies();
   } else if ($event_type == 'module.enabled') {
      $this->setModuleRelatedDependencies();
   } else if ($event_type == 'module.preuninstall') {
      $this->unsetModuleRelatedDependencies();
   } else if ($event_type == 'module.preupdate') {
      // TODO Handle actions before this module is updated.
   } else if ($event_type == 'module.postupdate') {
     // TODO Handle actions before this module is updated.
   }
}
```

Then create those function in your files **setModuleRelatedDependencies** OR **unsetModuleRelatedDependencies**

Like this

```
function setModuleRelatedDependencies(){
   global $log;
   $moduleName = Vtiger_Module::getInstance('YourModule');
   foreach ($this->dependentModules as $module) { //Defind How many module you want in dependent
       $moduleInstance = Vtiger_Module::getInstance($module);                                 

       $moduleInstance->setRelatedList($moduleName, 'YourModule', array(),'get_dependents_list'  );
   }
      $log->fatal('Successfully added Module Related lists');
 }
```

This is For the uninstall your plugin

```
function unsetModuleRelatedDependencies(){
    global $log;
    $moduleName = Vtiger_Module::getInstance('YourModule');
    foreach ($this->dependentModules as $module) {//Defind How many module you want in dependent
        $moduleInstance = Vtiger_Module::getInstance($module);

         $moduleInstance->unsetRelatedList($moduleName, 'YourModule', 'get_dependents_list');
    }
    $log->fatal('Successfully removed Module Related lists');
```

}